# Android: Finding if the device has Dual Sd cards

Tags: android, sd-card

There are some new devices like Samsung Galaxy that comes with two sd-cards. I want to know if there is any way to find if a device has two sd-cards or a single sd-card. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way is to check list of available roots using

```
File[] roots=File.listRoots();
```

Since `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns reference only to primary/default SD card